# Creating a Top 10 chart from existing nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm looking at the most efficient way of creating a Top 10 chart in Neo4j. The chart would need a position and relate to the item.

This is what I think but please correct me if I am wrong.

**Song**

```
Title
Artist
```

**Chart**

```
Name
Position
```

An example would be:

```
Sugar             :: Maroon 5    --->  Local Radio Top 10 :: 1
Thinking Out Loud :: Ed Sheeran  --->  Local Radio Top 10 :: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest putting the position on the relationship between the song and the chart.  This might be your relationship:

```
(:Song)<-[:HAS_SONG]-(:Chart)
```

And the `HAS_SONG` relationship can have a `position` property which determines the order.

Also, depending on what you're doing and if there is a lot of overlap of artists you might consider an `Artist` node

Comment: Thanks again Brian! That's two pints I owe you. This was just an example of what I am trying to achieve.